# JS: Making prototype function

Tags: javascript

I want to make a JS prototype function that mimics the Python syntax of `'a' in 'abc'`.

It works as expected in the first example but not in the second. What am I doing wrong?

```js
String.prototype.in = function(input) {
  return input.indexOf(this) > -1
}

console.log('a'.in('abc'))
// equivalent of 'abc'.indexOf('a') > -1
// true

console.log('a'.in(['a']))
// equivalent of ['a'].indexOf('a') > -1
// false
```

Comment: well if you want to pass in array, than one must code to handle that....

Comment: @epascarello You have it the wrong way round. The array is being passed into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primitive values such as numbers, strings, etc.. can't have methods in javascript.

So whenever you call a method on a primitive, it will be coerced into its object form.
(Similar to "boxing" in languages like java or c#)

Small example to illustrate the difference:

```js
// number primitive
let primitive = 12;
console.log(primitive);
// number object
let object = new Number(12);
console.log(object);
```

The object forms of primitives mostly behave in the same way as their primitive counter-parts, however there are a few differences, for example equality:

```js
console.log(12 == 12); // true
console.log(new Number(12) == new Number(12)); // false

// mixed comparisons
console.log(new Number(12) == 12); // true (boxed value will be unboxed)
console.log(new Number(12) === 12); // false (strict equality)
```

The reason why your second example `'a'.in(['a'])` is not working, is because `Array.prototype.indexOf` will check each element for strict equality (`===`).
The `this` string is currently in its object form, but the `'a'` in the array in its primitive form - so they are **not** equal.

In order to get the `in()` function working, you need to "unbox" the string value.
You can do so by using the [`Object.prototype.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method, which will return the primitive value:

```js
String.prototype.in = function(input) {
  return input.indexOf(this.valueOf()) > -1
}

console.log('a'.in('abc')); // true
console.log('a'.in(['a'])); // true
```

Comment: This is correct, I've forgotten that 'this' is passed an object. valueOf or '"' + this "'" will do the trick.

Comment: @RobKwasowski np, glad i could help :)